# When I use += to add a number to an array, it always ends up being 0, no matter what the number is

Tags: c++, arrays, math

I am trying to write code for my robot that keeps track of where it has driven, so that it can know where it is on a Cartesian grid (I am basing it off of this document: http://thepilons.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Tracking.pdf).

In the beginning, `absolute_position[0] (x-coordinate)` and `absolute_position[1] (y-coordinate)` are both `set to 2`, meaning the robot `starts at (2,2)` on the grid. **In the first loop**, before the robot has moved (meaning left, right, and back `variables are all set to 0`), `absolute_position[0] and absolute_position[1] are both set to 0`.

As far as I can tell, varCos and varSin should both be 0, so

```
absolute_position[0] += varCos;
absolute_position[1] += varSin;
```

should evaluate to

```
2 += 0;
2 += 0;
```

but as I said, they both end up at 0.
if I try replacing varCos and varSin with 0, or if I set them both to 0 (rather than offset_global[0] * cos(offset_global[1])), absolute_position ends up being [2,2] like I would expect.

Complete code:

```
double absolute_position[2] = {2,2};
double theta0;
double left = 0;
double right = 0;
double back = 0;
double prevLeft = 0;
double prevRight = 0;
double prevBack = 0;
double deltaLr = 0;
double deltaRr = 0;
double deltaBr = 0;
double deltaL = 0;
double deltaR = 0;
double deltaB = 0;
double thetar = 0;
double theta1 = 0;
double deltaTheta = 0;
double thetaM = 0;
double offset_local[2];
double offset_global[2];
double varCos = 0;
double varSin = 0;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

void positionTracking(){
    float sL = 10.5;
    float sR = 10.5;
    float sB = 6.5;
    while(true){
        //stores current encoder values
        left = -leftEncoder;
        right = rightEncoder;                                                   
        back = backEncoder;

        //finds the distance traveled for each wheel in inches
        deltaL = (left - prevLeft) * 3.25 * M_PI / 360;
        deltaR = (right - prevRight) * 3.25 * M_PI / 360;
        deltaB = (back - prevBack) * 3.25 * M_PI / 360;

        //updates the last values of the encoders to be used next cycle
        prevLeft = left;
        prevRight = right;
        prevBack = back;

        //calculates total accumulated encoder values
        deltaLr += deltaL;
        deltaRr += deltaR;
        deltaBr += deltaB;

        //calculates new absolute orientation
        theta1 = thetar + (deltaLr - deltaRr) / (sL + sR);
        if(theta1 < 0){
            theta1 += 2 * M_PI;
        }
        else if(theta1 >= 2 * M_PI){
            theta1 -= 2 * M_PI;
        }

        //find the change in orientation
        deltaTheta = theta1 - theta0;

        //find local offset vector
        if(deltaTheta == 0){
            offset_local[0] = deltaB;
            offset_local[1] = deltaR;
        }
        else{
            offset_local[0] = 2 * sin(deltaTheta / 2) * (deltaB / deltaTheta + sB);
            offset_local[1] = 2 * sin(deltaTheta / 2) * (deltaR / deltaTheta + sR);
        }

        //calculate the average orientation
        thetaM = theta0 + deltaTheta / 2;

        //converts cartesian to polar and changes the angle
        offset_global[0] = sqrt(pow(offset_local[0], 2) + pow(offset_local[1], 2));
        offset_global[1] = atan(offset_local[1] / offset_local[0]) - thetaM;

        //converts polar offset back to cartesian and adds it to the absolute_position
        varCos = offset_global[0] * cos(offset_global[1]);
        varSin = offset_global[0] * sin(offset_global[1]);

        absolute_position[0] += varCos;
        absolute_position[1] += varSin;

        //updates the old orientation to be used next cycle
        theta0 = theta1;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You said they "should" have certain values, but have you done any debugging to verify what the values actually are?

Comment: "As far as I can tell, varCos and varSin should both be 0" I would start by validating that asusmption.

Comment: *As far as I can tell, varCos and varSin should both be 0* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler.  Every programmer in existence has written programs where they are "sure" of things, until the program runs and then they find out their assumption isn't true.  When they debug the program, they find out their mistake(s) and make the proper changes.

Comment: Why you didn't embed all these variables in a `struct` or `class`? Doing so you can easily initialize them, track the values...

Comment: why do you use `float` for `sL`,`sR`, `sB`?

Comment: It is in general not a good idea to test on exact equality of double values, e.g. `if (deltaTheta = = 0)`. When the value is very small but not 0 (round-off errors) the division will result in unexpected behaviour. In this case also `offset_global[1]` and the sine/cosine might not be what you expect.

Comment: When I look at the value of varCos and varSIn, they are 0. The only reason I said they "should" be 0 is because I would expect absolute_position to evaluate to 2 rather than 0.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I didn't use a struct or class because I am new to c++, and I never heard of that before. I just did a little research and it seems like they are mostly for grouping variables, but I don't know why I would want to do that. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: @milbrandt       My understanding of floats is that they aren't as accurate as doubles, but in this case, all I needed was one decimal point.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], I can't reproduce the issue with the code posted

Comment: @CarlosStewart Yes, float are not as accurate as double. But you also have a lot of implicit conversions between float and double - which slows down your program and each conversion is a possible error (range and/or round off)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the screen on the robot said varCos and varSin were 0, but when I ran the program on my computer (not the robot) it said they were NaN. I changed it to

```
varCos = offset_global[0] == 0 ? 0 : offset_global[0] * cos(offset_global[1]);
varSin = offset_global[0] == 0 ? 0 : offset_global[0] * sin(offset_global[1]);
```

to make sure they are numbers.